# Python: how to reverse multiple slice manipulation of a string

Tags: python, string

I am working on an interesting Python coding question:

Take every 2nd char from the string, then the other chars, that are not every 2nd char, and concat them as new String.
Do this n times!

For instance:

"This is a test!", 1 -> "hsi  etTi sats!"
"This is a test!", 2 -> "hsi  etTi sats!" -> "s eT ashi tist!"

The function I wrote is:

```
def encrypt(text, n):
    if n <= 0:
        return text
    else:
        a = encrypt(text, n-1)[1::2]
        b = encrypt(text, n-1)[::2]
        return a+b
```

This seems to work, shown by the results of a testing function. But now I don't know how to reverse this action. For instance, with ("hsi etTi sats!", 1) as input, how shall I manipulate it so it can be restored to "This is a test!"? I know how to take every other character of a list, but how do you put them back. I am still in the early stage of learning Python, so I guess this is due to holes in my knowledge of something fundamental.

```
String = "ABCDEF"
a= String[1::2] = "BDF"
b= String[::2] ="ACE"
```

How do you manipulate a and b so that String can be restored? I am not sure if I have clarified myself.

Thank you for your time in advance.

Comment: You would need to split your string in half first, and then take letters alternating from both strings. Do this n times

Comment: Yes, precisely. I was stuck at taking letters alternating from both strings part. I just simply don't know how to do it haha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of the other answers lack up to two important aspects of your full question

- What happens when number of characters is odd? The last character will be missing if you `zip` or `map` sequences of unequal length.
- What about recursive encryption?

So here's your decrypt function:

```
def encrypt(text, n):
    if n <= 0:
        return text
    else:
        a = encrypt(text, n-1)[1::2]
        b = encrypt(text, n-1)[::2]
        return a+b

def decrypt(text, n):
    if n <= 0:
        return text
    else:
        a, b = text[:len(text)//2], text[len(text)//2:]
        text = "".join(map(lambda x, y: x + y, b, a))
        text = decrypt(text, n-1)
        if len(b) > len(a):
            # happens for odd number of characters. We need to append last from b
            text += b[-1]
        return text

s = "This is a test!"

print("n=1: {0}".format(decrypt(encrypt(s, 1), 1)))
print("n=2: {0}".format(decrypt(encrypt(s, 2), 2)))
print("n=3: {0}".format(decrypt(encrypt(s, 3), 3)))

>>> n=1: This is a test!
>>> n=2: This is a test!
>>> n=3: This is a test!
```

Comment: I honestly cannot dream of an even more thorough and comprehensive answer than this. Thank you so much sir. As a python rookie, I get to learn about map and zip through the answers here. But could you care to explain what (lambda x, y: x + y, b, a) means to me please? Or if you can give me some relevant material to read up on, that would work as well. Thank you so much sir!

Comment: I did read up a little bit on map function and lambda. But why does "".join(map(lambda x, y: x + y, b, a)) works while directly using map(lambda x,y: x + y, b, a) will only produce nonsense for me? It seems like a superfluous step to me. Thanks.

Comment: @Bowen: `map(lambda x,y: x + y, b, a)` yields a list (python2) or an iterator-object (python3). Each element of the result will be the sum of the zipped elements of `a` and `b`. Sum of strings is concatenation. So you have an iterable of 2-character-strings after the `map` (or `zip`). You then need to put these 2-character strings one after the other. That's what `join` does (here with an empty string as separator).

Comment: Thank you so much. You are very good at explaining things sir. I will sure play around more with map and lambda more to get a good grip on it.

Answer (score 1):

It is simply `zip` operation on the strings. You can't just use `zip` directly however, need to format it to string.

```
s = "ABCDEF"
a = s[1::2]
b = s[::2]

print(a,b)

s2 = "".join(["{0}{1}".format(x, y) for (x, y) in zip(b, a)])

print(s2)


>>> BDF ACE
>>> ABCDEF
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but could you care to explain the format part please? "s2 = "".join(["{0}{1}".format(x, y) for (x, y) in zip(b, a)])" Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

By using `zip` you can loop through two lists simultaneously. By adding `end=""` to `print` function, it continues to print at the same line.

This should work:

```
expression="This is a test!"
first=expression[1::2]
second=expression[::2]

for i,j in zip(first,second):
    print(j+i,end="")
```

Hence the output is:

```
This is a test
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I honestly didn't know the zip function. I tried it without adding "end='' " first and it just gave me the print result in multiple rows. This end= input works like a charm. How does it do this? Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

From your question it seems to me that you wish to create a separate function that can be used to decrypt a string encrypted using your encrypt function.  If so, then something similar to the following can be done:

```
def decrypt(text, n):
  if n <= 0:
    return text
  else:
    num = len(text) // 2
    a = text[:num:]
    b = text[num::]

    answer = "".join(map(lambda x,y: x+y, b, a))
    answer = decrypt(answer, n-1)

    return answer if (len(text) % 2 == 0) else answer + b[-1]
```

Comment: The answer provided by @ascriptor should be accepted since it was provided first and fully addresses the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `map` to concatenate the elements of `b` and `a` pairwise, which yields a list of strings of length 2. Then use `join` to concatenate these into the original string:

```
a = "BDF"
b = "ACE"
s = "".join(map(lambda x,y: x+y, b, a))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Would you care to explain what lambda is and why it is used in this instance please? Thanks!